# "Call to a member function store() on null"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload an image using a vue component, and the image is handled on the backend using laravel.

here is my products controller where the image field is supposed to be handled

```
  public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
        'product_name' => '',
        'selectedCategory' => '',
        'selectedSubcategory' => '',
        'volume' => '',
        'type'=> '',
        'brand' => '',
        'transmission' => '',
        'consumption' => '',
        'numberplate'=> '',
        'yom' => '',
        'processor' => '',
        'operatingSystem' => '',
        'storageType' => '',
        'storageCapacity'=> '',
        'memory' => '',
        'display' => '',
        'ad_status' => '', 
        'condition'=> '',
        'price' => '',
        'attachments' => '',
        'description' => '',
        'formData' => '',
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('formData')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->products()->create([
            'product_name' => $data['product_name'],
            'selectedCategory' => $data['selectedCategory'],
            'selectedSubcategory' => $data['selectedSubcategory'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'subcategory' => $data['subcategory'],
            'volume' => $data['volume'],
            'type'=> $data['type'],
            'brand' => $data['brand'],
            'transmission' => $data['transmission'],
            'consumption' => $data['consumption'],
            'numberplate'=> $data['numberplate'],
            'yom' => $data['yom'],
            'processor' => $data['processor'],
            'operatingSystem' => 'operatingSystem',
            'storageType' => $data['storageType'],
            'storageCapacity'=> $data['storageCapacity'],
            'memory' => $data['memory'],
            'display' => $data['display'],
            'ad_status' => $data['ad_status'], 
            'condition'=> $data['condition'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'attachments' => $data['attachments'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'formData' => $imagePath,
            'liquorData' => $data['liquorData']
        ]);
```

Here is my vue component's html

```
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Product Image</label> 

                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" @change="onFileSelected">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning text-white" @click="onUpload()">Add New Post</button>
                    </div>
```

And here are my methods

```
data () {
            return{
                categories : {},
                subcategories : {},
                product_name : '',
                price : '',
                description : '',
                image : null,

              ***************
                  }
            },
            onFileSelected(event) {
                this.image = event.target.files[0]
            },
            onUpload() {
                const formData = new FormData
                formData.set('image', this.image)
                console.log(formData);
                axios.post('/p', formData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            },
```

The vue component is handling all the other fields correctly except the image field. When I click submit I get a network error:

```
"Call to a member function store() on null"
```

This is a laravel error which tells me the issue is on the backend. But it was working perfectly before I moved everything to a vue component. For some reason it is sending a null value to the backend. Any help will be much appreciated

Here is the stack trace

```
0: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php", line: 54,…}
1: {,…}
2: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php", line: 261,…}
3: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php", line: 204,…}
4: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php", line: 725,…}
5: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 141,…}
6: {,…}
7: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
8: {,…}
9: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
10: {,…}
11: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
12: {,…}
13: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
14: {,…}
15: {,…}
16: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
17: {,…}
18: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
19: {,…}
20: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
21: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 116,…}
22: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php", line: 726,…}
23: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php", line: 703,…}
24: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php", line: 667,…}
25: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php", line: 656,…}
26: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",…}
27: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 141,…}
28: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\DisableBrowserCache.php", line: 19,…}
29: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
30: {,…}
31: {,…}
32: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
33: {,…}
34: {,…}
35: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
36: {,…}
37: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
38: {,…}
39: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
40: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php",…}
41: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
42: {,…}
43: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 180,…}
44: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php", line: 116,…}
45: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",…}
46: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",…}
47: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\public\index.php", line: 52, function: "handle",…}
48: {,…}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the stack trace on that error?

Comment: Your `request('formData')` is returning null suggesting there is no `formData` key present in the `request()`. What is the output of `dd(request()->has('formData'))`;?

Comment: @ewong let me edit the question to add the stack trace

Comment: @Peppermintology it returns false, which is now what I am not understanding. Does that mean it's a vue error? And if so, then why is vue sending a null property? Am I not handling the formData correctly in my component? Every online source I have looked at shows that's the correct way of sending files over

Comment: If it is returning `false`, that means the `formData` key is not present in the request and is likely not being sent from your Vue component.

Comment: How do I set the key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
public function store(Request $request){
 //then use $request->input('input-name');
```